# Count redirects

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, count

I found a redirect script, and I've been trying to get it to count the redirects (`url_hits`). Can't get it to work and I was wondering if someone out there could help me.

This is the part that redirects:

```
if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    $redirect = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = '".addslashes($_GET['url'])."'"));
    $redirect = "http://".str_replace("http://","",$redirect[url_link]);
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');  
    header("Location: ".$redirect);
}
```

And this is the database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `urls` (
  `url_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `url_link` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `url_short` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `url_date` int(10) default NULL,
  `url_ip` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `url_hits` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`url_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I see no `UPDATE table SET hits=hits+1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point in your code do you increase the hit counter.

Add this line after `if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {`:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `urls` SET `url_hits` = `url_hits`+1 WHERE `url_short` = '" . addslashes($_GET['url']) . "'");
```

---

Bonus: To avoid violating the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you could change that to:

```
$urlShort = addslashes($_GET['url']);
mysql_query("UPDATE `urls` SET `url_hits` = `url_hits`+1 WHERE `url_short` = '$urlShort'");
```

Which would enable you to change this:

```
$redirect = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = '".addslashes($_GET['url'])."'"));
```

To this:

```
$redirect = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = '$urlShort'"));
```

Comment: It almost worked, but now it adds +1 to all url_hits and not just the one that is clicked/redirected.

Comment: @Sinopa I think you're using the code I posted within the first few seconds... I edited it since then. Try now.